# stream a video in html page from apache tomcat server directory in spring mvc

Tags: java, apache, maven, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to play video with xyz.mp4 format from local (apache tomcat)server directory. I've created a folder under webapps in server directory. 
Thanks in advance..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/videoplay", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String videoplay(Model model, 
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)  {

    File objFile=new File("D:\\server tomcat\\webapps\\UPLOADS\\Videos\\SetWet.mp4");

    model.addAttribute("video", objFile);

    return "videoplay";

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="shuttle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="shuttle.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Video element.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please add a question. What problem do you have, what error do you get. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for writing good questions

Comment: i got html page with video player stamp but when i clicked on play button it wont play video and i have a doubt is it good approach for my task?!

Comment: Just update your post and write your question in there, for other people who read your question the first time. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the video file in `Model` and assume that it will play in the HTML Player.

An HTML Video Player requires a video file source which is a Stream of Bytes. Sending a file in a `Model` will not stream it as Bytes.

Have a look at the [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/asynchronous-streaming-request.html) I did sometime back. You can do achieve the playing by using Spring's `StreamingResponseBody`. Full source code available in [github](https://github.com/shazin/itube)