# Spring boot with thymleaf video playing task

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In database having videos related path like 'H:/testing/1.mp4,' these are user uploaded videos then I want to play these video on thymleaf with spring boot when the user login his account I wrote everything until getting user-related data "the problem is how to play the videos on thymleaf video tag"  please

Controller code:

```
List<Postings> findByUserVideos = postingService.findByUserVideos(Id);
model.addAttribute("data", findByUserVideos);
```

thymleaf code:

```
<video th:each="file : ${data}" width="100%" controls                                           poster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg">
<source th:src="${file.preview}" type="video/mp4">                                              
    </video>
```

Error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///H:/testing/1.mp4

Comment: It seems you are trying to play video in browser from local drive. It is not possible. You should insert the link to your BE endpoint, which gives you video data.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974581/stream-a-video-in-html-page-from-apache-tomcat-server-directory-in-spring-mvc

You can't set the video file in Model and assume that it will play in the HTML Player.

An HTML Video Player requires a video file source which is a Stream of Bytes. Sending a file in a Model will not stream it as Bytes.

Comment: can you give sample code for that # DDovzhenko

Comment: yes, but I am only sending the local path name like "H:\testing\1.mp4" this path actually store in the database .and video it will store my local drive when I fetch from the database it gives local path name like "H:\testing\1.mp4"  actually I am thinking like that is it the right way? @Mebin Joe